# List of exceptions to "Remove unused usings" in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I love the "Remove unused usings" command in VS2008, however when running it on a small file I find that it can remove certain usings which I would like to always be there, even if currently unused. For example, `System.Linq` - because unlike actual types, one can't Alt+Shift+F10 add the usings for extension methods.

Is it possible to specify a list of usings to be skipped by this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible to define such a command.